# dragable controls in runtime Similar to a toolbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, report, toolbox

I want to create a project in WPF for designing a custom report.
For this, I need a library to add controls to a panel, canvas, etc. with drag and drop at runtime.
Controls should be resizable and moveable with the mouse. Finally I want to print this.

Comment: You are asking too much. You start something first

Answer (score 1):

Telerik's WPF controls contain the [Diagram Control](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/diagrams.aspx) which supports the features you mention out of the box. I use it for a very similar scenario as you describe and it works well. The might be a counterpart offered by Infragistics as well.

With .[NET framework's built in features](http://www.wpftutorial.net/draganddrop.html) and/or free libraries you will able to cover the drag&drop part. You will have to implement the rest yourself which is possible but too much to ask for one question.

Comment: thanks. but i can not use telerik or etc. components in my project. i must use only wpf,C# and .net framework 4.

Comment: @Marc, am working on similar kind of project, but in our case we have to provide controls like textbox, checkbox, radiobtns, btuttons user will drop these controls on to form, can you give some idea on how to implement this.

Comment: @Marc, we want a develop similar like asp 2.0, where we drop a control, when we select it open properties window to select the options. How can achieve this with wpf

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I came across this. Take a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

There are 4 parts that show how to do a toolbox with what you're looking for.